# Login credentials in app publishing to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an iOS app created for government where insurance company can register and use it for compulsory insurance task. for uploading it to app store I must give username and password for app review, but for that I must create fictive insurance company what I can't do, because every company login with it phone number and unique code given by government (I just can't describe to government workers, that we must create fictive company). What I can do in this situation for app uploading?